# What's the LSTM model's output_node_names?

Tags: tensorflow, freeze, lstm

all. I want generate a freezed model from one LSTM model (https://github.com/roatienza/Deep-Learning-Experiments/tree/master/Experiments/Tensorflow/RNN). In my option, I should freeze the last prediction node and use "bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_binary=true --input_graph=model_20170913/model.pb --input_checkpoint=model_20170913/model.ckpt --output_graph=model_20170913/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=ArgMax_52"(ArgMax_52 is last default node name). However, I got one notice "Converted 0 variables to const ops." (freeze command's result). Now, I have no idea about which node_name should be as output_node_name?

Comment: Before saving, I print all node names.  In these nodes, "ArgMax" and "ArgMax_i"(i>=1 && i<=52), to my surprise，use "bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_binary=true --input_graph=model_20170913/model.pb --input_checkpoint=model_20170913/model.ckpt --output_graph=model_20170913/frozen_graph.pb --output_node_names=ArgMax" can generate freeze model!

Comment: I changed the code "return tf.add(tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) , biases['out'], name="lstm_prediction")". Whether can I regard "lstm_prediction" as output_node_name?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, "lstm_prediction" is output_node_name. And Tensorboard help me a lot to understand the graph.